# SQLAlchemy - dataframe to SQL

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have a table on my SQL server with x number of columns that have the same column names as the dataframe in my Python script. Is there a way to ignore all the columns in my python dataframe that are not present in the table on the SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to properly order and subset only the needed columns. Assuming you are using Pandas `to_sql`:

```py
df.reindex(my_db_columns, axis='columns').to_sql("myTable", engine, if_exists='append')
```

And if needing to retrieve column names run a quick query and extract the `keys`:

```py
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:pwd@my_database")

# RETRIEVE COLUMN NAMES
result = engine.execute("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable") 
my_db_columns = [col for col in result.keys()]

# SUBSET DATA FRAME AND EXPORT TO DATABASE
df.reindex(my_db_columns, axis='columns').to_sql("myTable", engine, if_exists='append')

engine.dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Happy Friday.

If you have a dataframe with columns e.g.

```
| id | name | address | state | zip | country | continent |
```

and you only want

```
| state | zip | country | continent |
```

You can define a different dataframe that only takes those columns and use that like so:

```
data_lite = data[['state', 'zip', 'country', 'continent']]
```

Comment: Do note, `reindex` is the [recommended alternative](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated) to indexing a data frame by columns over a list, `[]`.

Comment: True, Parfait! Thank you. Just trying to make a point to make a copy instead of changing the original so you can track changes.